# Between Subject Design with multiple Trials per participant

Tags: regression, anova, mixed-models, experimental-design, multilevel-analysis

Between the subject experiment with two groups: Each group has a pair of 10 participants. (Player 1 and Player 2) Pairs in both groups play a game where one factor is manipulated. Hypothesis: The score of group A is higher than Group B.

Can I use mixed modeling with random intercept as Player and team as intercepts?

What is a good way to analyze this experimental design?

Comment: I believe this is not the correct place for this question as it has no code/programming related. Also, why would you do anova/regression and not just a simple non-parametric hypothesis test, comparing both groups average score? Unless you know population data is normally distributed, then you can try with a t-test after testing for heteroskedasticity.

Comment: @CeliusStingher it was modeling related hence posted it here. I have multiple measure from the same participant( so that's why the intuitive way to do hypothesis test didn't seem right)

Comment: I understand, however remember this place is oriented to programming. You can check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to see what is wrong with this question. If you were to add an attemp you tried, and the code failed or is giving inconsistent results, then we will gladly help you. However this is broad (the question is lacking lots of information too) and you aren't submiting any attempt, mostly asking for an opinion. I suggest https://stats.stackexchange.com/ is a better place for this question.